# rpm error - Can not run any package

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, rpm, centos6, yum

I try to install some package using yum, but there is a big problem, I don't know how to solve it. Please help me, thank so much!^^
This is yum error:

```
[root@localhost rpm]# yum
rpmdb: /var/lib/rpm/__db.001: Input/output error
error: db3 error(5) from dbenv->open: Input/output error
error: cannot open Packages index using db3 - Input/output error (5)
error: cannot open Packages database in /var/lib/rpm
CRITICAL:yum.main:

Error: rpmdb open failed
[root@localhost rpm]#
```

after that, I try to re-build rpmdb but:

```
[root@localhost rpm]# rm -rf /var/lib/rpm/__db.00*
rm: cannot remove `/var/lib/rpm/__db.001': Input/output error
rm: cannot remove `/var/lib/rpm/__db.002': Input/output error
rm: cannot remove `/var/lib/rpm/__db.003': Input/output error
rm: cannot remove `/var/lib/rpm/__db.004': Input/output error
[root@localhost rpm]#
```

And this is list file and permission:

```
[root@localhost rpm]# ls -l
ls: cannot access __db.001: Input/output error
ls: cannot access __db.004: Input/output error
ls: cannot access __db.002: Input/output error
ls: cannot access __db.003: Input/output error
total 52456
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2887680 May 26  2016 Basenames
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    12288 May 26  2016 Conflictname
-????????? ? ?    ?           ?            ? __db.001
-????????? ? ?    ?           ?            ? __db.002
-????????? ? ?    ?           ?            ? __db.003
-????????? ? ?    ?           ?            ? __db.004
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1368064 May 26  2016 Dirnames
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  5251072 May 26  2016 Filedigests
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    16384 May 26  2016 Group
...
[root@localhost rpm]#
```

Comment: I guess the problem in hard drive. Check HDD

Comment: I agree with @MeiramChuzhenbayev this seems like a disk error. I'd recommend handling this as if that system were facing imminent failure.

Comment: Thank for your comment. Just reboot and it working well, I still don't know the reason exactly. ^^